# Having some trouble understanding loops

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I created this for some reason neither one of the queries are being updated

```
<cfloop index="i"  from="1" to="#ArrayLen(location)#">

    <cfif location[i] NEQ "" AND #locationID# EQ "" >

        <cfquery Name="UpdateAddActivity" DATASOURCE="#DS#">        
            INSERT INTO tblProjectLocations
            (   
                projectID,
                locationID
            )
            VALUES
            (   
                #ProjectName#,
                #location[i]#
            )
        </cfquery>

    </cfif>

    <cfif location[i] EQ "" AND #locationID# NEQ "" >

        <cfquery Name="UpdateAddActivity" DATASOURCE="#DS#">        
            DELETE FROM tblProjectLocations
            WHERE locationID = #locationID# AND projectID = #ProjectName# 
        </cfquery>              

    </cfif>

</cfloop>
```

Am I looping correctly? It doesn't seem like to me that the accumulator is ever going to be updated but loops are done this way every place that I've looked.

Comment: The locationid variable looks like a bit of a mystery.  From where does it come?

Comment: It helps to test your data by adding <cfdump var="#location#"> and perhaps <cfdump var="#locationid#"> to make sure that the values are as you expect them to be.

Comment: By the way, the pound signs in `#locationID# EQ ""` are superfluous. Also, I hope that in your actual code you're using `cfqueryparam`.

Answer (score 2):

**Your [cfloop](http://cfdocs.org/cfloop-index-loop) tag is fine** - you only need index/from/to attributes for a basic loop.

The `index` variable is incremented (and the loop re-processed) at the position of the closing tag. Or to put it another way, the body code is executed once for each index value between `from` and `to` (inclusive).

For information, you can change the default increment (of 1) by specifying the `step` attribute (though that obviously doesn't make sense for an array loop).

When your code isn't performing as expected, you can debug it with the [dump](http://cfdocs.org/cfdump) tag:

```
<cfloop ... >
    ... 
    <cfdump var=#locationID# abort />
    ...
</cfloop>
```

The `abort` attribute will stop processing - the loop will not iterate and the current page content will be returned (it's shorthand for specifying [cfabort](http://cfdocs.org/cfabort) tag separately.

You can use multiple dumps, and the `label` attribute to help identify which is which, but obviously if using abort attribute make sure only the last one has it.

As has been mentioned `locationID` isn't defined in the snippet you've provided, so may be the issue.

Sometimes spaces can cause issues - you may want to use the trim function to ensure you're dealing with empty strings (though blindly wrapping trim functions everywhere is ugly - always try if possible avoid introducing spaces).

### Shortcut Array Looping

The from/to loop you've got there is only one type of cfloop - there are [others](http://cfdocs.org/cfloop).

Specifically, when you don't need the numeric index, there is a shorthand array loop:

```
<cfloop index="CurLocation" array=#Location# >
    ...
</cfloop>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
<cfloop index="i" from=1 to=#ArrayLen(Location)# >
    <cfset CurLocation = Location[i] />
    ...
</cfloop>
```

But without the unused `i` variable. (If you need the `i` variable, stick to from/to.)

Note that inside a function you should almost always write `index="local.i"` and `index="local.CurLocation"` to ensure the variables are appropriately scoped. This isn't unique to loops - it applies to any tags that create variables. You can also do `<cfset var i = 0 />` prior to the loop to do the same thing.

### Unrelated Issues

There are a couple of other issues with your code.

Most importantly, **the code you're showing is potentially at risk of SQL injection**. You should almost never write SQL with bare hashes in, and instead parameterise your queries - using [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) tag - to solve this. (In the situations where you *can't* use parameters (e.g. within `ORDER BY`) make sure you have appropriately sanitized any dynamic text.

Less important -- it doesn't change how the code works, but does betray a lack of experience and understanding -- are the superfluous hashes around `locationID`. A simplified explanation is that you generally only need `#`s inside strings (i.e. where the contents would otherwise be treated as text, rather than being a variable's value.)

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, look at your data.

```
<cfoutput>

<cfloop index="i"  from="1" to="#ArrayLen(location)#">
 i is #i# <br>

<cfif location[i] NEQ "" AND locationID EQ "" >
 true location is #location[i]# <br>
<cfelse>
false location [i] is is #location[i]# and 
locationid is #locationID# <br>

</cfif>

<cfif location[i] EQ "" AND locationID NEQ "" >
 same as above
</cfif>

</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Then you'll know why you are not getting the results you expect.

Comment: `#locationID#` should be `locationID` in your cfifs

Comment: True, but I simply copied from the OP.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have to copy the op :)  #var# was documented as bad practice at least as far back as cf 6 by macromedia, possibly later but all the old docs are hard / impossible to find.

Comment: Bad practise? :/ It's certainly not good practise, but aside from being ugly and a sign of not understanding, it's not really the end of the world. Not that I agree with blindly copying the OPs misuse either though - [insert comment about cliffs and lemmings] ;o)

Comment: The quote I pulled from livedocs in 2005 was. 
Macromedia recommends that you use pound signs only when necessary. The following example shows the preferred method for referencing variables. 

<cfset SomeVar = Var1 + Max(Var2, 10 * Var3) + Var4>
In contrast, note the following example, which uses pound signs unnecessarily: 

<cfset #SomeVar# = #Var1# + #Max(Var2, 10 * Var3)# + #Var4#>

Comment: Sure, but I think there's a difference between bad practise (for example, not properly encoding/parameterising variables) and something that is unnecessary, not recommended, pretty annoying, but not really harmful. \*shrug\*

Comment: The way it was explained to me was that it caused cf to evaluate the expression again needlessly, of course now I can't find anything to support that so I dunno.  But yeah, ugly for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are items in your location array, the loop will run and the CFLoop tag will take care of incrementing i.

What I'd guess is happening is that you are checking two conditions within the loop and if neither match, no code will run. You're handling these:

```
location[i] NEQ "" AND #locationID# EQ ""
location[i] EQ "" AND #locationID# NEQ ""
```

but not these:

```
location[i] EQ "" AND #locationID# EQ ""
location[i] NEQ "" AND #locationID# NEQ ""
```

Could that be it?